# Ember, disable input based on condition

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-rails

I have an Ember form, where I want to disable input's based on the user. 
I get an array of modifiable fields from my back end.

How do I get this to work with Ember? 
Ideal scenario would be to do this,

```
{{input type="text" disabled=isModifiable("middleName") value=middleName}}
```

I know that isn't possible. 
Fairly new to Ember, advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Define a property in you Controller or Component like this:

```
fields:[],
loadFields : function(){
 var that = this;
 $.get(FIELDS_API).done(function(serverResponse){
    //process server response in an array with objects with this form:
    // [ field:"middleName", isDisabled:true}]

   that.set("fields",fieldsArray);
 })
}
isModifiable : function(fieldName){
 var field = this.get("fields").findBy("field",fieldName);
 return (field) ? field.isDisabled: false;
},
isMiddleNameInputDisabled : function(){
    return this.isModifiable("middleName");
}.property("fields.@each")
```

Use that property in your template like this:

```
{{input type="text" disabled=isMiddleNameInputDisabled  value=middleName}}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have about 20 different fields. I find creating 20 different method names redundant. Anyway out of that?

Comment: You can make a custom component that extends the input view and gets a fieldName parameter. The component should decide if the input is disabled or not. {{custom-input type="text" fieldName="middleName" value=middleName}}

Comment: Okay. What if I want to do this for any type of input? What about a select box, datepicker, textarea etc?

Comment: Ember.js respects separation of concern - (data, logic and UI code all live in different areas). That's why I've recommended the use of properties for each field. Logic should not be implemented in the template.